# Как настроить dns для субдомена расположенного на виртуальной машине?

Tags: proxmox, debian, dns

Есть сервер, на нем стоит BIND9, proxmox. Все вроде настроено по "лучшим рецептам".Однако появилось необходимость для домена site.ru сделать субдомен (sub.site.ru) и расположить его в контейнере (proxmox). Подскажите, как настроить dns, что бы по адресу sub.site.ru, стучась на любой порт я мог попадать в контейнер (proxmox).

Comment: Собственно абсолютно так же, как и без proxmox. Попробуйте по первому хауту, найденному в гугле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ситуацию, то вопрос относится не столько к DNS, сколько к виртуальной машине.

У Вас видимо проблема в том, чтобы получить доступ к виртуальной машине извне. Решение будет зависеть от того, каким образом на Вашей виртуальной машине настроен сетевой интерфейс. Типовые варианты - NAT или Bridge. В случае NAT Вам требуется настроить трансляцию портов на сервере виртуальных машин. В случае bridge разобраться с выделением IP в Вашей сети, возможно настроить DHCP.